# why does find work inside makefile but not glob **/*.proto for protoc compiler

Tags: shell, makefile, protocol-buffers, protoc

I recently wrote a Makefile instruction for compiling **.proto** files and ran into odd behavior.

This command works when running in my own shell, but when inside a Makefile target...

```
    protoc \
        --proto_path ./protos \
        --go_out ./protos/gen \
        --go_opt paths=source_relative \
        --go-grpc_out ./protos/gen \
        --go-grpc_opt paths=source_relative \
        ./protos/**/*.proto
```

...it fails with:

```
Could not make proto path relative: ./protos/**/*.proto: No such file or directory
```

However, this ***does*** work inside the Makefile:

```
    protoc \
        --proto_path ./protos \
        --go_out ./protos/gen \
        --go_opt paths=source_relative \
        --go-grpc_out ./protos/gen \
        --go-grpc_opt paths=source_relative \
        $(shell find ./protos -name '*.proto')
```

The only difference is the last argument.

Specifically, inside the Makefile:

- **This correctly expands all the files:** `$(shell find ./protos -name '*.proto')`
- **But, this does not:** `./protos/**/*.proto`

**My question is** How come the expansion of files via `./protos/**/*.proto` does not work with Make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because make invokes `/bin/sh` as its shell, and `/bin/sh` is a POSIX shell which does not support `**` as a globbing operation.

Using `**` to mean "search all subdirectories" is non-standard, extra feature of some shells like bash, etc.